# Какой аналог TStrings (Delphi) есть в Java?

Tags: java, android

Собираюсь заполнить массив строками (с переносами строк) и потом перенести в TextView целиком массив.

Comment: Можете попробовать `ArrayList<String>`, но вообще лучше просто в обычной строке расставить `\n`.

Comment: Вам может показаться странным, но многие представления не имеют, как работает TStrings (Delphi) и вникать в его работу вряд ли будут, чтобы только помочь вам. Опишите более подробно, какой именно результат вы хотите получить